# Stop Time Sync Between Host and Guest - VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, time

So I've been googling and I've tried the following commands. I want to stop the virtual machine from having the correct time and just to stick with what time it last recorded. The host operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 and the guest is Windows XP. I've turned time syncing off in XP so it won't do that when I connect to the Internet. However it does appear to take the time from ubuntu and set it as it's own.

```
VBoxManage setextradata XP11 “VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage” 200

vboxmanage setextradata XP11 "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" "1"
```

Both commands haven't work as the time is always set to the exact same as Ubuntu's. I've located the extradata entry in the virtualbox XML file. It states both changes that the commands above are set to make. But of course it still hasn't stopped updating the time.

```
<ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="1152,864"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="74,52,1152,911"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" value="1"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="&#x201C;VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage&#x201D;" value="200"/>
    </ExtraData>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you'r trying to set the WarpDrivePercentage that the line should be:
`<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage" value="200"/>`
While in your version has html markup for " " around the VBoxINternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage, probably inserted by the previously applied command.

Comment: I completely over looked that. I changed the vbox file so that line is correct and upon booting the machine up again it's back to the exact correct time.